# Assume that x is a solution to the following linear system Ax = b where A is an n × m matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Assume that x' is a solution to the following linear system Ax' = b where A is an n × m matrix, with n < m, x' is an m-dimensional column vector and b is an n-dimensional column vector.

If x⊥ is a vector orthogonal to x', is x' + x⊥ also a solution to the above linear
system?

Comment: The answer is no

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general the answer is no.  For instance, consider
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&1}, \quad b = 1.
$$
Then $x' = (1,0)$ and $x^{\perp} = (0,1)$ are orthogonal, but $x' + x^\perp$ is not a solution.

---

In general, we can say that $x' + v$ will be another solution to $Ax = b$ if and only if $Av = 0$, or equivalently if and only if $v$ is orthogonal to every row of $A$.